# What is the purpose of horizontal navigation (using arrow keys) inside Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-explorer, selection, navigation

Pressing up/down selects the items in a folder. When the right/left arrow key is pressed, a blue box appears around the date/type/size of the particular item. What is its purpose? Is it just there for aesthetic reasons?

I tried pressing the menu key, but it only shows the regular context menu.

[Blue box when using right/left arrow keys in Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkkb.png)